# Migrating contacts2.db from eclair to gingerbread

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am working on android framework level and my query is;
I have an eclair phone which contains more than 500+ contacts. Now I want to upgrade my phone from eclair to gingerbread. Since I don't want to lose my contacts, I am planning to use the eclair contacts db(contacts2.db) as it is in Gingerbread...but I found that gingerbread has some extra Table and columns under Contacts2.db...
So my query is how should i migrate contacts2.db from eclair to gingerbread ???
Let me know if I am not clear and really appreciate if somebody can help me )

Answer (score 0):

To save effort and time you can export your existing contacts to vCard format using the export functionality found in the Contacts tab context menu, and accessible programmatically as `ExportVCardActivity`. It will create a single file on your SD card.

You will be able to import contacts back on any other device, including Android.